# sql logical constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012, name of my table is "tableX", it has color_id and there is second table "colortable1[color_id]"
= key is color_id pointing to colortable1,

now we have too many colors and we must archive some of them.
we split the colortable into 2 color tables:

```
colortable1( color_id is 1-100)
colortable2 (color_id is 100-100000)
```

after the split tableX will not find ids that were removed from colortable1
and I need to somehow set logic:

```
if id is 1-100 then color_id is from colortable1
if id is 100-100000 then color_id is from colortable2
```

how can this be done in SQL?

Comment: SQL-2011 is the ANSI SQL standard, there's no SQL-2012 standard.

Comment: 100,000 rows is not very large.  You should be able to solve your performance problems with table partitioning or indexes and not have to resort to using a separate table.

Comment: What's your version of SQL Server? Is it Standard or Enterprise?

Comment: If you really want to use this logic only, I dont think this is possible without creating a stored proc. Or the best possible solution is the one provided by `THE @GordonLinoff`

Comment: What happens if color_id is 100? You should not split that table into two. 100k is not much data. consider using indexes and optimist the access to the table.

Comment: Have you considered a horizontal table partitioning?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL languages does not provide any (good) abstraction and generalization. However the RDBMS are **very good** in handling large rows (1M rows is absolutely ok).

Instead of spliting rows in different tables, use just one table and use values in columns (you can create extra distinctive column) to resolve the records.